# Call from java Main class from servlet Application

Tags: java, servlets

I Have two applications.One is Standalone application.Another one is web Application (Servlet App).
Here I want to Call Java Application From Servlet Application.So can You Guys Suggest Me or Can i have one app for this one.So that i will implement in my application.
In this Application I have created Jar file of Stand alone Application After that What to do ?

Comment: Add this jar to your webapp ?

Comment: `MainClass.main(null)`

Comment: Thank for Reply...@Smutje .But i didnt get U...

Comment: @Maksym  If i add jar file,automatic it will call or not..

Comment: @mdrazi `"JavaApplication".main(null);`

Comment: Not, but you will have opportunity to run it whatever you want and whenever you want.

Comment: In That Servlet Class ,What i have to write?...@Maksym

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should make your command line application classes available in your web applcaction environment. To achieve this you should either:

1. package all in one jar
2. put classes of stand alone application under `WEB-INF/classes` in you `war`
3. put jar that contains your stand alone application under `WEB-INF/lib` in you `war`

Stand alone application starts from `main()` method. You can just call this method from your servlet and pass parameters, for example: `MyApp.main("hello", "stand alone application")`.

Since you are the author of both applications and are familiar with the internal design of the stand alone application you could (and probably should) call internal layer directly without using `main()`. For example if you main method starts with `new MyApp().start()` perform the same call from your servlet.

Comment: Yeah if copy MyApp.class and put into WEB-INF/classes.After that when i create war file of Web App.That MyApp.class is not showing in file structure..

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand you comment. If it is an additional question could you please give me more details?

Comment: As per your concern ,i have added MyApp.class in to WEB-INF/classes folder.while creating war file,this class file is not showingin classes folder.

Comment: if i am able to success build war file ,i can import MyApp Class in servlet class Right!!!!

Comment: So, do you have problems now?

Comment: ok now two class file i stored into WEB-INF/classes folder of webApp.After that i am not able to import MyApp class in to servlet Application..why?

Comment: Do you mean that you have compilation or runtime problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just Switch from GlassFish to Tomcat , And then your problem has been solved.